# Returning nested array from mongodb and native node driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document that's setup like this:

```
{
 _id : '',
 name : '',
 friends : [
    {'name' : ''},
    {'name' : ''},
    {'name' : ''} 
 ]
}
```

I want to select just the 'friends' array and get the array of objects to iterate through.  However, when I do this:

```
this.collection.find({'_id' : _id}, {'friends' : 1}).toArray(function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

This returns an array that looks like this:

```
[
  friends : [
      {'name' : ''},
      {'name' : ''},
      {'name' : ''} 
   ]
]
```

Ideally, it would only return:

```
[
    {'name' : ''},
    {'name' : ''},
    {'name' : ''} 
]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is being returned right now? `[friends: [...]]` is incorrect syntax. `[{friends: [...]}]` or `{friends: [...]}`?

Comment: Sorry, it's `[{friends : [{...}]}]`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to return only the friend's array. But using `findOne` instead of `find` you could at least shed off that outermost array. So instead of accessing the data using `res[0]['friends']` it would be `res['friends']`.